# sun.nio.ch counterpart classes on Android

Tags: java, android, nio, sun

I've some Java SE source code which uses `sun.nio.ch.*` classes, but on Android these `sun.nio.ch.*` are not available. How can I replace all `sun.nio.*` classes with their counterparts on Android. Any suggestions on getting started or complete replacement for `sun.nio.*` ?

Thanks,
Abdul

Comment: Since very few developers use `sun.nio.ch`, perhaps you could explain what specific classes you are using from there, and what you are using them for.

Comment: I'm using sun.nio.ch.SelChImpl interface, and I don't know exactly what it does, since I'm not Java expert. I just wanted to know if I can replace this with Android-counterpart, and get it working out of the box. I would appreciate if you tell me what it does, and point some relevant tutorial.

Comment: Change your code to use only what's in `java.nio.channels,` and castigate the person who wrote this code with extreme severity. There is a specific warning in the Javadoc about not using `sun.*` classes in your own code.